# Can I develop websites on Xampp and publish on windows based server? (PHP/IIS 6/7/Apache)

Tags: php, iis, windows-server-2003

I usually develop websites on the WAMP/XAMPP and host it on Linux servers. All works fine. But to meet some of the client requirements, we need to host a new project on to a Windows based server running IIS (I guess its IIS7, if not IIS6).

I don't have access to a windows server on my local. So how I can develop with having an understanding that it would work fine when hosted on the Windows. My main concern is with .htaccess stuff. For example, URL rewriting.

I have been googling around and could see that I can do something with ISAPI filters.

Are there more things I should care about (other than .htaccess)? 
Which ISAPI filter you would recommend to me?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is running Apache on the Windows server an option?

Comment: I did think about this but I found that we can't. So its IIS.

Comment: you're using wamp/xampp normally, meaning you're on a windows machine, every windows machine has IIS. where's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site mentioned earlier is http://php.iis.net/

If its Windows 2003 Then the guide is:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/247/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-60/

If its windows 2008 then the guide is:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/246/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-70/

.HTACCESS files are not used in IIS, so if you make an extensive use of those then you will have issues.  For URL re-writing I use Ionic's ISAPI Rewrite Filter:
http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/IIRF.aspx

Comment: I had the same issue and used Ionic's ISAPI Rewrite Filter, and have had no problems. I am using it for a Zend Framework project on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can run Apache on Windows 2008.  We do it...

Alternatively, if you do want to run [PHP in IIS7](http://blogs.msdn.com/david.wang/archive/2006/04/04/HOWTO_Install_and_run_PHP_on_IIS7.aspx), it is easy:  MS has an [entire site dedicated](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/) to apps that can be installed directly to IIS (and a bunch of them are PHP)